# Alternatives for PrintStacktrace() method in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, try-catch, printstacktrace

I have recently run my code through PMD. And there's this jsp, in which someone has written, a try catch block (I know its a bad practice.) .

The code goes something like this

```
<%
 Thread t = new Thread(runA);
 String tClassName = null;
 tClassName = request.getParameter("classname");
 t.setName(tClassName);
  t.start();
 %>


 <%!
   Runnable runA = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
      try{
          // some code here   
          }
      catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();            
          }

          }
         };
    %>
```

Now the PMD tool suggests not using the `printStackTrace()` method, since it is likely to cause security vulnerability.

Could Somebody please suggest an alternative for the `printStackTrace()`, to use inside the catch block. And please note this code is on a jsp page.

Comment: Java codes in JSP? It's not recommended.

Comment: It's not the try-catch that isn't a great idea, it's that there are scriptlets at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to log the exception, it is more appropriate to use some logging framework (like Log4j) and use

```
log.error("Ops!", e);
```

The benefit is the logging framework logs to a correct log file on server. The `e.printStackTrace()` writes just to the `System.err`.